# Variable sized classes and memory mapped files

Tags: .net, serialization

Is there an accepted way to store variable sized classes in memory mapped files, or is this always considered bad practice?  Essentially I want to store a collection of image patterns files that are third party classes in MMF.  Once they are loaded, they are read only.  They are guaranteed to be less than a given size, so I was planning on allocating blocks and having a fixed starting position for each block.

It seems MMF really is designed around using fixed-size data blocks (especially structures) or streams (such as binaryreader/writer).  I'm assuming I'll need to use some streaming approach.  Any recommendations for getting the least performance hit when streaming lots 20MB files?

Comment: Yes they are.  There was no point in making the wrapper any fancier because that would just duplicate what the operating system already does.  It uses MMFs internally to implement named pipes, local loopback sockets and files.  Not taking advantage of those features is almost always a mistake.

Comment: So basically I'm going to have to serialize/deserialize classes for streaming when using MMF unless they are simple data types?